# How to get list of themes (Theme name) installed in Windows 7?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I want to write an application in MFC which gives me a list of theme installed in windows 7.

Which library or dll provide the themes so I can use it in my application to change the theme using my application or can I have code snippet ?

Regards,
Mehul.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate files under %WinDir%\Resources\Themes and %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes.

The format of .theme files is documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773190(v=vs.85).aspx